# MultiLojas Checkouts Diferentes

Tags: magento

Tenho um cliente que possui 2 lojas físicas que estarão na mesma loja virtual.
Uma equipe cuida da parte de roupas *fitness* e outra a de suplemento.

O cliente gostaria de 2 lojas diferentes em uma mesma instalação ***magento***
Mas ele quer *checkouts* diferentes porque uma loja trabalha com um tipo de parcelamento e a outra com outro tipo.

É possível ter multilojas com *checkouts* diferentes?

Answer (score 1):

Possível é sim. O problema é que sempre que eu tentei isso, esbarrei em problemas relacionados aos gateways de pagamento, maioria deles não aceita um checkout múltiplo.

Imagine que a URL de resposta da transação seja diferente para cada loja, os gateways de pagamento não permitem que você tenha múltiplas URLs de retorno na mesma conta. Por isso tive que implementar uma fachada para o pagamento, tenho um site dedicado a pagamento, onde os callbacks de pagamento sempre apontam para a mesma URL, porém lá eu filtro eles e envio para a loja correta.

Answer (score 0):

tem como sim!! O magento disponibiliza vários módulos de pagamento, por exemplo, voip, pague seguro , paypal e entre outros. Suponha que você queira usar o "pague seguro" para finalizar os pagamentos das duas lojas, você pode definir 2 checkouts com valores diferentes, ou criar duas contas do "pague seguro" se quiser manter as finalizações de forma mais organizadas, ou seja, uma finalização vai para conta do João e a outra para Maria...

Answer (score 0):

Bom não sei como esta sendo tratado no Magento.

Mas o Magento permite ter 2 ou mais lojas na mesma instalação, para cadastrar uma nova loja acesse no admin aba Sistema/Gerenciar Lojas.

Se for ter os mesmo produtos em ambas as lojas compensa criar uma visão, a visão e como outro idioma, voce conseguiria alterar preços etc pois o mesmo produto estaria em ambas visão.

Agora se for produtos diferentes, com segmentos diferentes conforme você sitou o ideal é realmente criar lojas.

Após ter essa parte de loja ou visão criadas, acesse os meios de pagamentos.

Quando estiver em meios de pagamentos altere o escopo conforme imagem [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

para qual visão ou loja quer configurar as diferenças, assim você consegue dizer que ambas tem o mesmo meio de pagamento com diferenças.

Também é possível instalar checkouts diferenciados para cada visão ou loja dessa mesma maneira, em uma loja ou visão você ativa o novo checkout e na outra desativa, caso queira novos checkouts [clique aqui](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=osc&pl=0)